# Single column/multiple column index, what is better?

Tags: database, db2, query-optimization, indexing, database-indexes

I have one poor performing procedure with couple of queries in it.

I have identified few temp table queries that does scanning of temp table. I decided to add index on temp table to avoid table scanning. I have noticed that there are multiple columns of temp table which are being used in where clause. However, I am not sure whether I should include all columns in single index (composite index) or multiple indexes with one column each index to gain the maximum performance.

Database is DB2

Comment: It would be better to post your procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends greatly on your queries and the data on your table. As a rule of thumb you should include only the columns that reduce greatly the result rows.

If the where clause for first limiting column already drops for instance 90% of the rows and the next one would only reduce a few hundred rows anymore it is not worth the resources to include in the index. Always keep in mind that the database engine works first with the first column of composite index, and then proceeds to the next ones. If your queries have the columns in different order the index will potentially start even slowing your queries down.

Also, if you have a lot of data and using several indexed columns seems worth it you might in some cases want to have separate indexes and have intra-parallelism work. It is possible that running parallel index lookups using several CPUs has better performance - if your server has to spare.

Answer (score 1):

In case of MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the first two columns, the first three columns, and so on.

If you specify the columns in the right order in the index definition, a single composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same table.

Lets say that you have `INDEX nameIdx (last_name,first_name)` created on table test

Therefore, the **nameIdx** index is used for lookups in the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name='Widenius';

SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE last_name='Widenius' AND first_name='Michael';

SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE last_name='Widenius'
  AND (first_name='Michael' OR first_name='Monty');
```

where as name **nameIdx** is not used for lookups in the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name='Michael';

SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE last_name='Widenius' OR first_name='Michael';
```

for more detail refer [URL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

summary of this is if you are using columns in where clause as mentioned in index order (from left to right ) then it is better than single column index